Как сделать ожидание ответа из клавиатуры на сообщение в aiogram
Мне нужно чтобы бот ловил ответ пользователя на сообщение и понимал на какое сообщение ответил пользователь
Бот отправляет пост с персонажем и ждет оценку персонажа пользователем.  или . При этом нужно чтобы после получения  ответа пользователь понимал какого персонажа оценивал пользователь

Бот: Xinyan из Genshin Impact
Пользователь: 
Бот: Вы отреагировали  на персонажа Xinyan

Проблема в том, что когда бот получает ответ через @router.message(F.text == '') он не знает на какого персонажа отреагировал пользователь

Если именно ответ на сообщение, то у сообщения есть reply_to_message

Так как в кнопки клавиатуры нельзя передавать данных кроме как тех которые можно записать в сам текст кнопки, я советую вам использовать инлайн кнопки где можно передать какую-то информацию через callback_data. тык и тык2
